# how to apply color effects of camera in video recording with front camera?

Tags: android, android-camera, video-capture

Is there any way to apply default color effects of camera in video recording for front camera using myCamera.getParameters().setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NEGATIVE); for negative and other effects

Answer (score 0):

You must set parameters in your `CaptureRequest.Builder`, there you can apply all the effects that you want:

```
int colorEffectValue = 
//Choose your effect:
//CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_MONO
//CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_NEGATIVE
//CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_SOLARIZE
//CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_SEPIA
//CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_POSTERIZE
//CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_WHITEBOARD
//CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_BLACKBOARD
//etc, you can find all modes in CameraMetadata
youtCaptureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE, colorEffectValue);
```